# How to change style of ASP.NET AJAX control toolkit password strength extender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, controls, toolkit

I am trying to implement an password strength indicator for my project. However I do not want to show the password strength next to the text-box where the password is entered. Here is my markup snippet:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" runat="server" />

<asp:TextBox id="txtPasswordRepeat" runat="server" />

<asp:PasswordStrength runat="server" ID="passwordStrength"
    TargetControlID="txtPassword"
    StrengthIndicatorType="Text"
    PreferredPasswordLength="10"
    PrefixText="Strength: "
    MinimumNumericCharacters="0"
    MinimumLowerCaseCharacters="0"
    MinimumSymbolCharacters="0"
    RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="false"
    TextStrengthDescriptions="Weak;Medium;Strong"
    CalculationWeightings="50;15;15;20"
    TextCssClass="tab_colspan" />
```

Now I want to display the password strength text below those textboxes. However setting the DisplayPosition-Property only changes the absolute position of the output label relative to the txtPassword textbox. Setting this property to "BelowLeft" will result in displaying the password strength above the other text box.

What I need is an possibility to overwrite the style-property of the output label or a way to insert the label into the DOM so that it gets rendered relative to the other elements on the form. Is this possible somehow?

Thanks in advance!